# Rabbitmq: different between envelop.message.body and envelop.message.pool

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

I have one producer based on `nodejs` and the javascript library which I used is [amqp.node](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node), and the consumer is implemented by [C library](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c).

From rabbitmq management web, I can see the messages are pushed into the queue and delivered to the consumer. In the consumer, the `amqp_consume_message` return `AMQP-RESPONSE-NORMAL`, however, the `envelop.message.body` is null. How can I debug it in this case?

Here are my codes to consume messages from rabbitmq

```
amqp_rpc_reply_t reply;
amqp_envelope_t envelope;
amqp_maybe_release_buffers(m_con); 
timeval m_time;
m_time.tv_sec = dwMilliseconds/1000;
m_time.tv_usec = (dwMilliseconds%1000)*1000;
reply = amqp_consume_message(m_con, &envelope, &m_time, 0);//time out 1 second
if (AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL != reply.reply_type)
{
    return false;
}

bool bRet = false;
amqp_bytes_t& rTheBody = envelope.message.body;
if (rTheBody.len > 0)
{
```

**Update**

After further investigation, I find those messages are stored in the `envelop.message.pool.pages`. I want to the different between `message.body` and `message.pool`?

Comment: What is amqp-c? The [clients](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html) page only lists rabbitmq-c and a few amqp-cpp projects. Can you give a link to the project?

Comment: Here is the [link](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [this](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/issues/253)

> The pool field of the `amqp_message_t` object (e.g.,
>   `envelope.message.pool`) is a memory pool used for allocating parts of
>   the message. It is an implementation detail and should not be used by
>   client code directly (this implementation detail is subject to
>   change).
>
> The only reason that the `envelope.message.body.bytes` should be NULL
>   with a `AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL` return value is if a 0-length message body
>   is received.